# Return first instance of a row with multiple values in WHERE clause, based on a boolean in AND clause

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table:

```
ID  Value Timestamp
A   False     0
A   True      0.1
B   True      0.2
B   True      0.3
C   False     0.4
C   True      0.5
```

I am trying to create a singular query, where I search multiple files (WHERE ID in fileA, fileB, fileC) to find a file that meets 2 criteria:

1. The value of that file at some point has to be True
2. The first instance/occurrence (timestamp) of the row's value must be False
   So then I could return both A and C because they meet both criteria, but not B

Comment: There is no timestamp on your data, there is no way of knowing which one is the first.

Comment: The table is made up, I dont need the actual timestamp row, I just need the ID's that match the criteria. They are ordered by date when I run actual queries

Comment: One of your rules states `The first instance/occurrence (timestamp) of the row's value must be False` in order to accomplish that a timestamp field is definitely **required** you can't rely on the IDs (as they repeat as strings). If you need this you need to show (even if made up) data that actually is close to what you have in your database.

Comment: I edited it to reflect the data

Comment: Tag your database / SQL engine

Answer (score 1):

```
select   id 
        ,min("Timestamp")   as "Timestamp"
from     t
group by id
having   min(case Value when 'False' then "Timestamp" end) < 
         min(case Value when 'True' then "Timestamp" end)
order by id
```

| id | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| C | 0.4 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8d337dcccc429d77491dfbfd404f83b2&hide=1)

Comment: This doesn't take into account that the first values is "false".

Comment: It works because the true false is actually 1 or zero, i've tested it and the query works like a charm, thank you very much @DannySlor

Comment: True/false vs 0/1 is irrelevant. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0369ac23e78c24a71cba6931b812f7ef

Comment: @DannySlor I appreciate the effort, unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem. The sample data doesn't include any true-to-false sequences so it will still return an invalid result.

Comment: Please see updated answer